# A question that involves permutations of pairs of row elements

Tags: arrays, numpy

Consider two numpy arrays of integers.   U has 2 columns and shows all (p,q) where p<q.   For this question, I'll restrict myself to 0<=p,q<=5.   The cardinality of U is C(6,2) = 15.

```
U = [[0,1], 
     [0,2], 
     [0,3],
     [0,4],
     [0,5],
     [1,2],
     [1,3],
     [1,4],
     [1,5],
     [2,3],
     [2,4],
     [2,5],
     [3,4],
     [3,5],
     [4,5]]
```

The 2nd array, V, has 6 columns.  I formed it by finding the cartesian product UxUxU.  So, the first row of V is [0,1,0,1,0,1], and the last row is [4,5,4,5,4,5].   The cardinality of V is C(6,2)^3 = 3375.

A SMALL SAMPLE of V, used in my question, is shown below. ***The elements of each row should be thought of as 3 pairs.  The rationale follows***.

```
V = [[0,1,  2,5,  2,4],
     [0,1,  2,5,  2,5],
     [0,1,  2,5,  3,4],
     [0,1,  2,5,  3,5],
     [0,1,  2,5,  4,0],
     [0,1,  2,5,  4,1]]
```

Here's why the row elements should be thought of as a set of 3 pairs:   Later in my code, I will loop through **each row of V, using the pair values to 'swap' columns of a matrix M**.  (M is not shown because it isn't needed for this question)   When we get to row `[0,1,  2,5,  2,4]`, for example, **we will swap the columns of M having indices 0 & 1,  THEN swap the columns having indices 2 & 5,  and finally, swap the columns having indices 2 & 4**.

I'm currently wasting a lot of time because many of the rows of V could be eliminated.

The easiest case to understand involves V rows like `[0,1,  2,5,  3,4]` where ***all values are unique***.   This row has 6 pair permutations, but they all have the same net effect on M.  Their values are unique, so none of the swaps will encounter 'interference' from another swap.

**Question 1**:  How can I efficiently eliminate rows that have unique elements in unneeded permutations?
I would keep, say, `[0,1,  2,5,  3,4]`, but drop:

```
[0,1,  3,4,  2,5],
[2,5,  0,1,  3,4],
[2,5,  3,4,  0,1],
[3,4,  0,1,  2,5],
[3,4,  2,5,  0,1]
```

I'm guessing a solution would involve  np.sort and np.unique, but I'm struggling with getting a good result.

**Question 2**:  (I don't think it's reasonable to expect an answer to this question, but I'd certainly appreciate any pointers or tips re resources that I could study)  The question involves **rows of V having one or more common elements**, like `[0,1,  2,5,  2,4]` or `[0,5,  2,5,  2,4]` or `[0,5,  2,5,  3,5]`.   All of these have 6 pair permutations, but they don't all have the same effect of M.   The row `[0,1,  2,5,  2,4]`, for example, has 3 permutations that produce one M outcome, and 3 permutations that produce another.  Ideally, I would like to keep two of the rows but eliminate the other four.   The two other rows I showed are even more 'pathological'.

Does anyone see a path forward here that would allow more eliminations of V rows?   If not, I'll continue what I'm currently doing even though it's really inefficient - screening the code's final outputs for doubles.

Answer (score 1):

To get rows of an array, without repetitions (in your sense), you can run:

```
VbyRows = V[np.lexsort(V[:, ::-1].T)]
sorted_data = np.sort(VbyRows, axis=1)
result = VbyRows[np.append([True], np.any(np.diff(sorted_data, axis=0), 1))]
```

Details:

- `VbyRows = V[np.lexsort(V[:, ::-1].T)]` - sort rows by all columns.
  I used *::-1* as the column index to sort first on the first column,
  then by the second, and so on.
- `sorted_data = np.sort(VbyRows, axis=1)` - sort each row from *VbyRows*
  (and save it as a separate array).
- `np.diff(sorted_data, axis=0)` - compute "vertical" differences between
  previous and current row (in *sorted_data*).
- `np.any(...)` - A *bool* vector - "cumulative difference indicator" for
  each row from *sorted_data* but the first (does it differ from the
  previous row on any position).
- `np.append([True], ...)` - prepend the above result with *True* (an
  indicator that the first row should be included in the result).
  The result is also a *bool* vector, this time for all rows. Each element
  of this row answers the question: Should the respective row from *VbyRows*
  be included in the result.
- `result = VbyRows[np.append([True], np.any(np.diff(sorted_data, axis=0), 1))]` -
  the final result.

To test the above code I prepared *V* as follows:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  5,  3,  4],
       [ 0,  1,  3,  4,  2,  5],
       [ 2,  5,  0,  1,  3,  4],
       [ 2,  5,  3,  4,  0,  1],
       [ 3,  4,  0,  1,  2,  5],
       [13, 14, 12, 15, 10, 11],
       [ 3,  4,  2,  5,  0,  1]])
```

(the last but one row is "other", all remaining rows contain the same
numbers in various order).

The result is:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  5,  3,  4],
       [13, 14, 12, 15, 10, 11]])
```

Note that *lexsort* as the first step provides that from rows with
the same set of numbers the returned row will be the first from rows
sorted by consecutive columns.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  This gets part of the way there, but I have 2 concerns:   a) it eliminates ANY row having the same 6 elements in some permuted form.  But we need to eliminate only permutations of the 3 PAIRS of elements.    b) The output must show any row as it appears in the original array, but remove the PAIR PERMUTATIONS off that row.